# Transformation of a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$ into one on the complex plane

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

To gain a better understanding of vector fields and their flow computation, I wanted to experiment with a coordinate transformation: real coordinate in $\mathbb{R}^2$ <-> polar coordinates <-> complex plane. I have no problem with polar coordinates, but I got really confused, about how to deal with the transformation into the complex plane.

I have chosen a simple vector field that describes a counterclockwise circular movement:

$$ V = -y \partial_x + x \partial_y. $$

Given a starting point $(x_0,y_0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, we know that there exist an integral curve $\phi \colon (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ for some $\epsilon >0$. It also holds that

$$ \phi'(t) = \phi_1'(t) \partial_x + \phi_2'(t) \partial_y = V_{\phi(t)}. $$

So, to find $\phi$, we need to solve the following system of ODEs:

$$\phi_1'(t) = - \phi_2(t),$$
$$\phi_2'(t) = \phi_1(t).$$

A solution for a given initial problem is

$$ \phi(t) = (x_0 \cos t - y_0 \sin t, x_0 \sin t + y_0 \cos t) \in \mathbb{R}^2.$$

If we transform this solution into complex numbers, we get that $\phi(t) = (x_0 + i y_0) e^{it} =: z_0  e^{it}$. I find this form much easier to deal with, so I asked myself, how could I skip all this sine-cosine-computations, in such a way that I just need to solve something like

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi(t) = i \phi(t).$$

As in the case of the polar coordinate transformation, I started with the transformation of my vector field. Somehow I ended up on the Wiki page reading about the Wirtinger derivative (never heard about it before) and managed to transform my vector field to

$$ V = i (z \frac{\partial}{\partial z} - \bar{z} \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}).$$

After thinking a lot about this new form of the vector field and the result that I wanted to achieve with the complex exponential function, I understood that I have no idea how these two thoughts connect. I have a feeling that I try to combine apples with chairs. I do not know how to get to the point, where I can compare the components of the vector field and the velocity of the curve $\phi$ as I did it in the example above. Or in general, I don't really understand, how to find a flow for this complex vector field. I also don't understand, why I have two "components" ($\partial_z$ and $\partial_\bar{z}$). I have thought that I will get a vector field in the form of $V = i z \partial_z$, in my head, this would somehow connect to the solution that I have.

I would gladly appreciate any help in getting a (better) understanding of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a smooth function f(x,y), the equation for the integral curve $\phi$ is

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}f(\phi)=V[f]. \tag{1}
\end{align}

By using the real coordinate $(x,y)$, both sides of (1) become

\begin{align}
\mathrm{L.H.S.} &= (\dot x \partial_x + \dot y \partial_y)f,\\
\mathrm{R.H.S.} &= (V_x \partial_x + V_y \partial_y)f.
\end{align}

Hence we obtain

\begin{align}
\dot x &= V_x,\\
\dot y &= V_y,
\end{align}

and these ODEs are the same as you got.

On the other hand, both sides of (1) also become

\begin{align}
\mathrm{L.H.S.} &=(\dot x+i\dot y)\cdot\frac{1}{2}(\partial_x-i\partial_y)f+(\dot x-i\dot y)\cdot\frac{1}{2}(\partial_x+i\partial_y)f,\\
\mathrm{R.H.S.} &=(V_x+iV_y)\cdot\frac{1}{2}(\partial_x-i\partial_y)f+(V_x-iV_y)\cdot\frac{1}{2}(\partial_x+i\partial_y)f.\\
\end{align}

Hence, by introducing symbols

\begin{align}
z &= x+iy,\\
\bar z &= x-iy,\\
\partial_z &= \frac{1}{2}\big(\partial_x-i\partial_y \big ),\\
\partial_{\bar z} &= \frac{1}{2}\big(\partial_x+i\partial_y \big ),\\
V_z &= V_x+iV_y,\\
V_{\bar z} &= V_x-iV_y,
\end{align}

then the equation (1) becomes

\begin{align}
\dot z\partial_z+\dot {\bar z}\partial_{\bar z} 
= V_z\partial_{z}+ V_{\bar z}\partial_{\bar z}. 
\end{align}

Thus we obtain

\begin{align}
\dot z = V_z,\\
\dot {\bar z} = V_{\bar z}. 
\end{align}

We see that the first of the above is the complex conjugate of the second, and vice versa. Thus these are equivalent.

In the case $(V_x,V_y) = (-y,x)$, for example, we obtain $\dot z=iz$.

In the above discussion, we introduced $z$ and $\bar z$ but these are not coordinates of the (real) manifold $\mathbb{R}^2$. What are $\partial_z$ and $\partial_{\bar z}$ ?

To answer this question, it is convenient to define $\partial_z$ and $\partial_{\bar z}$ algebraically. Namely, for the tangent vector space $T_p\mathbb R^2 = \langle\partial_x,\partial_y\rangle$ and its complexification $\mathbb C\otimes T_p\mathbb R^2 = \langle \partial_x,\partial_y,i\partial_x,i\partial_y\rangle$, the operators $\partial_z$ and $\partial_{\bar z}$ are not members of the preferred but the latter.

The operators $\partial_z$ and $\partial_{\bar z}$ are just formal but useful in two-dimensional manifolds.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!